# Get random word and its parameters from json file

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parameters

I am trying to get the random word and its parameter from the JSON file.

**JSON file:**

```
{
    ranWord1 {
        sentence: "This is a sentence 1"
    },
    ranWord2 {
        sentence: "This is a sentence 2"
    },
    ranWord3 {
        sentence: "This is a sentence 3"
    },
    ranWord4 {
        sentence: "This is a sentence 4"
    },
    ranWord5 {
        sentence: "This is a sentence 5"
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
function readFiles() {
    var result = null;
    var file = 'dictionary.json';
    $.ajax({
        url: file,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
    });
    var lines = result.split(", ");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    return lines[randLineNum];
}
```

I am able to get the random word which in this case is `ranWord1`, `ranWord2`, `ranWord3`, `ranWord4`, `ranWord5`. But, I am not able to get the parameters. I would like to store, for example, `"This is a sentence 4"` in a local variable. Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

External word.js file:

```
var data = [
  ["ranWord1", "This is a sentence 1"],
  ["ranWord2", "This is a sentence 2"],
  ["ranWord3", "This is a sentence 3"],
  ["ranWord4", "This is a sentence 4"],
  ["ranWord5", "This is a sentence 5"]
]
```

JS:

```
function readFiles() {
var result = null;
        var file = 'word.js';
        $.ajax({
            url: file,
            type: 'get',
            data: 'data',
            dataType: 'script',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var randomData = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
                result = randomData;
                alert("word: " + randomData[0] + ", sentence: " + randomData[1]);
            }
        });
}
```

I am trying to get the array from an external file but now I am getting `undefined` for randomData[1] and I am getting anything including `[` and `]` for word

Comment: `var lines = result.split(", ");` ? Is expected result  string or object ?

Comment: firstly put your vars and return inside the success function or it will not work. Javascript will have tried to perform those tasks before the AJAX returns the json.

Comment: @user4756836 _"I am able to get the random word which in this case is `ranWord1`, `ranWord2`, `ranWord3`, `ranWord4`, `ranWord5`"_  `key` of parsed `json` string ?

Comment: @user4756836 See post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the ajax problem @AndyKillen has addressed, your JSON isn't valid. You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to check.

This would be valid JSON.

```
{
    "ranWord1": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 1"
    },
    "ranWord2": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 2"
    },
    "ranWord3": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 3"
    },
    "ranWord4": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 4"
    },
    "ranWord5": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 5"
    }
}
```

Also in your case you wouldn't even need such a complex json. A simple array would suffice:

```
[
    "This is a sentence 1",
    "This is a sentence 2",
    "This is a sentence 3",
    "This is a sentence 4",
    "This is a sentence 5"
]
```

(Unless you need some additional data in there)
That would also simplify your javascript code. You could do just:

```
$.ajax({
        url: file,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var randomSentence = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
        } 
    });
```

---

if you need the word you could also do:

```js
var data = [
  ["word1", "This is a sentence 1"],
  ["word2", "This is a sentence 2"],
  ["word3", "This is a sentence 3"],
  ["word4", "This is a sentence 4"],
  ["word5", "This is a sentence 5"]
]

var randomData = data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
alert("word: " + randomData[0] + ", sentence: " + randomData[1]);
```

Comment: My issue is that the random sentence has to go with its word so if my random function picks ` ranWord1 ` i want it to return ` This is a sentence 1 ` also

Comment: I like your second approach. My only problem with this solution is that... I have a really long list of words and sentences so I am pulling it through an external file that is why I used a .json file.

Comment: @user4756836 i just used the `data` array for this example. You could of course load the same data via ajax.

Comment: @user4756836 ah, sorry. remove the `var data = ` from the json file, I used that just for my example. It should start with `[`. As said you can check if it's valid here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job.

- wait for the json response
- get the object size
- create a random number
- make the var randomSentence the object sentence using the random number

````

```
var randomSentence = '';

function readFiles() {
  var result = null;
  var file = 'dictionary.json';
  $.ajax({
    url: file,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      jsonSize = getObjectSize(data);
      randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonSize);
      randomSentence = data[randNum].sentence;
    } 
  });
}

function getObjectSize(obj){
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
  }
  return size;
}
```

Ideally you would have a function call at the end of the success function and pass the result of the random sentence to that, rather than working with a global variable.

Comment: why do I need object size?

Comment: You're right, except you can't return the value from within the success function. By the time of the ajax callback, `readFiles` has already finished.

Comment: Objects do not have a length property, so you need to find out it's size.  Once you know it's size you can calculate the random number between 0 and max size. 

With that you can use the number to get the "ranWord" of choice by number and not the name.  eg, data[randNumber]

Then you can use the dot notation to get the sentence value data[randNumber].sentence

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var json = {
    "ranWord1": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 1"
    },
    "ranWord2": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 2"
    },
    "ranWord3": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 3"
    },
    "ranWord4": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 4"
    },
    "ranWord5": {
        "sentence": "This is a sentence 5"
    }
};

function readFiles() {
    var file = '/echo/json/';
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: file,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {json:JSON.stringify(json)},
        async: false        
    });
    return request.then(function(data) {
            var keys = Object.keys(data);
            var sentences = $.map(data, function(rand, key) {
              return rand.sentence
            });
            return [data, keys, sentences]
        }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          return errorThrown
        })

}

readFiles()
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response); // `response[0]`:`json` 
    var keys = response[1];
    var sentences = response[2]
    // do stuff with `keys`:"words" , `sentences`:"sentences"
    console.log(keys, sentences);
    // var lines = result.split(", ");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);
    console.log(keys[randLineNum]
               , response[0][keys[randLineNum]]["sentence"]);
    return keys[randLineNum]
           +":"+ response[0][keys[randLineNum]]["sentence"];
}, function(errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j4141k6a/1/